# How to reuse email operator in airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I have airflow job which perform the action and send the notification email in both success & failure events, below is the code I am using.

```
#from builtins import range
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

args = {'owner': 'Airflow','start_date': days_ago(2) }

dag = DAG( dag_id='download_extracts', default_args=args,schedule_interval=None, dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60))

task1 = BashOperator(task_id='task1',bash_command='sudo ipython3 /root/itg/src/scripts/task1_.py',dag=dag )
task2 = BashOperator(task_id='task2',bash_command='sudo ipython3 /root/itg/src/scripts/task2_.py',dag=dag )
task3 = BashOperator(task_id='task3',bash_command='sudo ipython3 /root/itg/src/scripts/task3_.py',dag=dag )

success  = EmailOperator(task_id='sucess_email',to='user@company.com',subject='task1 extract download status:- success', html_content='extract download completed',dag=dag )
failure = EmailOperator(task_id='failure_email',to='user@company.com',subject='task1 extract download status:-failed', html_content='extract download incomplete',dag=dag )

router = DummyOperator(task_id='router', dag=dag, trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED)

task1 >> success
task1 >> router >> failure

task2 >> success
task2 >> router >> failure

task3 >> success
task3 >> router >> failure
```

Now my concern is how to reuse both success/failure email operators for other tasks, by just changing email subject dynamically?

Comment: Any suggestions in my query?

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

Airflow comes out of the box with callbacks that are triggered on success and on failure. This is possible, both on Task and DAG level.

[`BaseOperator`](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/index.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator)

> **on_failure_callback** (callable) – a function to be called when a task instance of this task fails. a context dictionary is passed as a single parameter to this function. Context contains references to related objects to the task instance and is documented under the macros section of the API.

> **on_success_callback** (callable) – much like the on_failure_callback except that it is executed when the task succeeds.

> **on_retry_callback** (callable) – much like the on_failure_callback except that it is executed when retries occur.

[`DAG`](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html?highlight=dag%20model#airflow.models.dag.DAG)

> **on_failure_callback** (callable) – A function to be called when a DagRun of this dag fails. A context dictionary is passed as a single parameter to this function.

> **on_success_callback** (callable) – Much like the on_failure_callback except that it is executed when the dag succeeds.

So the easiest way in my opinion is to write a function that is mapped to these callbacks and that gets required information like the task/DAG name from the provided context.

### Option 2

If you want to stick with your approach, you could also write a custom EmailOperator which extends `EmailOperator` - Airflow provides some documentation on this: [Creating a custom Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/custom-operator.html).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Philipp. I will explore both options.